# How can manipulate the featues of layers

Tags: layer, geotools

I want to manipulate the featues of layers loaded in Jframe (I have multiple layers).You find below the code I use to charge the layers.Please, someone can help me.

```js
File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
        if (file == null) {
            return false;
        }

        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        FeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
        // get vertices of file
        // Create a map context and add our shapefile to it
        if (mapContext == null) {

        }
        // make it look prettier
        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema(), color[next]);

        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
        
        mapContext.addLayer(layer);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the features?

Comment: I want to apply some algorithms on them( such as Douglas-Peucker).